# GRPC Related issue Regarding Serialization of the data

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, grpc, grpc-python

Concat of Two serializer table data return the message after concat of two and then it returning me empty data. I want to concat the merchant_serializer_class and serializer_class return the data

Please help me with issue and look into this...

```
user.proto syntax = "proto3";

package config_routing;

service InitiateLinkController {
  rpc FetchMerchantData(ListRequest) returns (Attributes) {}
  rpc FetchSubMerchantData(ListRequest) returns (ListResponseSubMerchantData) {}
}

message ListRequest {
  int32 user_id = 1;
  int32 id = 2;
}

message User_Settings {
  bool is_multilingual_parameters_enabled = 1;
  int32 enable_nach_paper_base = 2;
}

message ListResponseData {
  int32 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string email = 3;
  string domain = 4;
}

message ListResponseSubData {
  int32 id = 1;
  string email = 3;
  bool is_active = 4;
}

message Attributes {
  ListResponseData Data = 1;
  ListResponseSubData subData = 2;
}
```

**user.py** (serializer)

```
class UserProtoSerializer(proto_serializers.ModelProtoSerializer): class Meta: model = User proto_class = initiatelink_pb2.Attributes # Modification here proto_class_list = initiatelink_pb2.ListResponseData fields = '__all__' depth = 1

class SubInfoProtoSerializer(proto_serializers.ModelProtoSerializer): class Meta: model = UserInfo proto_class = initiatelink_pb2.Attributes proto_class_list = initiatelink_pb2.ListResponseSubData fields = '__all__' depth = 1

def FetchMerchantData(self, request, context): print(request.id) print(request.user_id) final_dict ={} try: merchant_data = User.objects.get(pk=request.merchant_id) except User.DoesNotExist: self.context.abort(grpc.StatusCode.NOT_FOUND, 'Post:%s not found!' % merchant_data) merchant_serializer_class = UserProtoSerializer(data)

        print(merchant_serializer_class)
        final_dict.update({'Data' :merchant_serializer_class})
        try:
            if request.id:
                submerchant_data = UserInfo.objects.get(merchant=request.user_id,  pk=request.id)
                serializer_class = SubInfoProtoSerializer(submerchant_data)
                print(serializer_class)
                print(type(serializer_class))
                final_dict.update({'subData': serializer_class})
                
        except UserInfo.DoesNotExist:
            self.context.grpc_context(grpc.StatusCode.NOT_FOUND, 'Post:%s not found!' % request.id)
        return  ParseDict(str(final_dict), initiatelink_pb2.Attributes(), ignore_unknown_fields=True, descriptor_pool=True)
```